# JSF2 ignores empty alt attribute

Tags: jsf-2, image, glassfish-3, alt

I have a jsf snippet:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<!-- Yandex.Metrika -->
<img src="//mc.yandex.ru/watch/xxx" alt=""/>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika -->
</ui:composition>
```

But when I use it, web-client get HTML page whithout empty alt attribute in img element:

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika -->
<img src="//mc.yandex.ru/watch/xxx" />
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika -->
```

As result my document has validation error (

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Assign a value to the alt attribute. What is the benefit of passing W3C vlidation tests without actually dealing with accessibility.

Comment: He might be having images to be skipped by screen readers

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but I just wanted to point out that empty alt tags are actually accessibile. An alt tag may be empty if the image in question is described in it's current context and does not provide any user interaction. see http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#context

Answer (score 3):

You could use the JSF graphicImage component, which does render the empty alt attribute.

For Example:

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:image1.png']}" alt="" />
```

or

```
<h:graphicImage value="http://somedomain.com/somecontext/xxx/image1.png" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is a bug in JSF2 (JSF1.2 preserves empty attributes).
To 'workaround' that in JSF2, wrap code by `f:verbatim`, like this:

```
<f:verbatim>
   <img src="//mc.yandex.ru/watch/xxx" alt=""/>
</f:verbatim>
```